# Ir buscar o valor anterior de uma tabela sql em php?

Tags: php, javascript

Eu gostaria de encontrar uma forma de saber como efetuar o que desejo.

Eu tenho uma plataforma de notícias e gostaria que me apresentasse ao lado o video anterior que tenha sido inserido. Parece simples pois poderia apenas pôr para ir buscar o `(id)-1` e ficaria com o valor. Mas e se um dos videos for apagado? Iria haver um valor que estaria vazio e em consequência iria dar um bug. Existe alguma forma de o fazer?

Comment: Por serem noticias, você deve no banco de dados data/hora da postagem correto ?

Basta pegar a noticia X que está sendo exibida, buscar a data desta noticia, e verificar no banco o primeiro video recuando dessa data, ou também, recua um ID, caso não encontre, recua mais um e por ai vai.

Comment: Você se refere a vídeo anterior como aquele que foi assistido pela pessoa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você possui um campo onde armazena a data da notícia, você pode fazer:

```
SELECT <dados> FROM <tabela> WHERE <tabela.campo_data> < <parametro_data_com_data_do_video_atual> ORDER BY <tabela.campo_data> DESC LIMIT 1;
```

@Edit

Já no caso de usar apenas o ID, você pode simplesmente substituir os campos data pelos id's :

```
SELECT <dados> FROM <tabela> WHERE <tabela.campo_id> < <parametro_id_com_id_do_video_atual> ORDER BY <tabela.campo_id> DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

De fato, se você pegar `id - 1` pode acontecer de o vídeo anterior ter sido excluído. O que pode ser feito é pegar o id anterior mais próximo através da cláusula `LIMIT` e `ORDER BY`:

`SELECT video, id
 FROM tbl_Video
 WHERE id < $id
 ORDER BY id DESC
 LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0):

Você passando o ID que deseja no , você pegaria o registro anterior.

```
SELECT <CAMPO> FROM <TABELA> WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM <TABELA> WHERE ID 
< <VALOR.ID>)
```